# Tweeter API v1 issue with tweetable.js in my wordpress theme

Tags: twitter, wordpress, wordpress-theming

this question may sounds very odd but really I'm helpless. Few days ago a designer made a theme for me. After I paid him he just blocked my email address and stop giving reply to my emails and chats. Now, the problem is he made a custom twitter widget for my sitw which is working ok, but yesterday my friend told me that my sites runs on Twitter API 1.0 and I should have to upgrade to v1.1 otherwise they are gonna delete API v1. But really have no idea how to  work with twitter 1.1. The old method of v1 is showing error. I'm giving the link of files my developer used for the tweeter widget in my wordpress theme. If anybody can fix up the things and update this tweeter widget to v1.1 I will be really really glad and will gift a 50GB free box.com account because I really dont have anything more to give.
**Tweetable jQuery 1.6**
http:// bit. ly/ 10uDFyh

**Scripts.js** - Custom written by the developer
http://bit.ly/11flbwG   - Check the line of code 330 - 350

**Widget_twitter_tweets.php** - Wordpress widget file
http://www52.zippyshare.com/v/10645901/file.html

**My website:** iSaumya .com - Check the tweeter feed under the social icons in the home page. This plugin makes this works.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the (many) WordPress plug-ins to display your latest tweets as a widget.  They have the advantage of a much wider userbase and better support.

Comment: Yes, but if I use that, I will loose the look and feel of my custom plugin design. Thats the problem. You visit my site, this plugin is customly made for that space only.